# rails, only admin can see json page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

maybe someone did this before me, i cant handle with this. 
I have system where many users, admins. Im using `extJS, JSON, Rails.`

So, my question is: How in rails i can do that `www.mysite.com/user/54/?format=ext_json&_dc=1306937167419&start=0&limit=50&fields=["respondent[email]` CAN SEE ONLY ADMINS and just average users can see text "Sorry, only admins" ??

if simple, *.json pages can see only admins.

this is my controller

```
  def uz   
    @answers      = Question.find(params[:id])

    if session[:user].is_admin == 1

    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.ext_json { render :json => @answers.to_ext_json(:class => Answer, :include => [:respondent]) }
    end
  end
```

im tried this (create before_filter) but nothing

```
  def checking
    if session[:user].is_admin == 1
        WHAT TO DO HERE
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create before_filter in controller where you can check format, action and session and return 404 error page

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter

```
before_filter :admin_required

...

private
def admin_required


  case params[:format].to_sym
  when :ext_json 
     #....redirect with eror or something if not admin
  end
end
```

Comment: oh, i get it, i'm tried but nothing could you help me ? I check session(admin or not), but how to check format and return 404 ??

Comment: nice, workign perfectly, buuuut i noticed one mistake if in url i type ext_json, so it doesnt work , if i remove ext_ working. I tried to delete in format.ext_json prefix ext_, but still nothing, or type in admin-required when: ext_json, but it is not right?

Comment: I don't know about ext_json format , but I think you can just check for it  in source code , like



                           
when :ext_json (update answer)

Comment: thanks for this all help!:) when im trying when :ext_json, so i dont get my answers in extJS view ;/ it is some bug:S when i'm replace everywhere ext_json on json ALL my data dissapears:S